# Is it possible to query a Custom Post Type by Taxonomy and Term AND only those with a SPECIFIC child term?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm wondering how I could query the following setting:

`taxonomy` is: `projectcats`

`term` is: `design`

some posts have a child term: `reference`

I tried to only display the post with the specific child term `reference`, but don't know how:

```
<?php 
        query_posts(array( 
            'post_type' => 'projects',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'projectcats',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'design',
                )
            ),
            'showposts' => 10
        ) );  
    ?>
```

Comment: Edited with some cleaner formatting

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [`WP_Query()`'s Taxonomy Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters). You can make use of the `relation => AND` operator to query for posts that have both terms.

> Also take note that unless you've got a specific circumstance for modifying the main `$wp_query` object, you shouldn't be using [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) and should instead use the [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class.

If you need to use `query_posts()`, you can just move the `tax_query` array to your existing code, but here's something to get you started:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'projectcats',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'design',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'projectcats',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'reference',
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$project_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $project_query->have_posts() ){
    echo '<ul>';
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
            $project_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also after re-reading your question, you should also be able to just replace `'terms' => 'design'` with `'terms' => 'reference'`, no? You don't need to query the parent term if you don't want them.

Comment: Thank you for initiating a new learning process! I need both, as it takes place on single-projects.php. terms => 'design' was ment as example, this term is different on each single post, but 'reference' is attached as child term to other terms too.